# Message of Custom Exception Thrown Being Printed as Null

Tags: java, exception

Even though I have entered a custom message, that is not being printed when I print the message. Code below:

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    try {
        String poNumber=null;
        if(poNumber.equals(null))
        {
            throw new Exception("Services Purchase Order not created.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        info("Custom Exception Message: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Custom Exception Message: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't thrown your own `Exception`; you have caused a `NullPointerException` with `poNumber.equals(null)`, because `poNumber` is `null`.

Your catch block caught the `NullPointerException`, not your `Exception`, and its message is `null`.

If you really want to throw your own `Exception`, then change the condition to use `==`, to avoid the `NullPointerException`.

```
if (poNumber == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

public void run() throws Exception {

```
    try{

    String poNumber=null;
                if(poNumber==null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Services Purchase Order not created.");
                }
        }



            catch (Exception e) {


                info("Custom Exception Message: "+e.getMessage());

            }
```

this will give you the message you want

Answer (score 1):

You are catching the wrong exception:

```
poNumber.equals(null)
```

Will result in a *NullPointerException* (because you cannot call *equals* on *null*).
You have to rewrite it like this:

```
if(null == poNumber)
{
    throw new Exception("Services Purchase Order not created.");
}
```

Depending on your logging framwork you can also adjust your info() call to be like this

```
info("Exception occured", e);
```

so you will know next time which exception occured.